# recommended practice for form submission

Tags: forms

I want to create a form on a page but how do I handle the form submission.

Which hook should i implement to handle my submission? Probably dirtiest would be to do it in the theme itself but I don't want it that way... probably not the right way to do it

Comment: Are you just doing a contact form submission? What is the forms purpose? You handle forms in WordPress just like you would any other normal form - `$_GET` and `$_POST`.

Comment: @bigant841 Are you talking about a custom form or are would you like to use a plugin form?

Comment: it's a form that will create posts, comments with my plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use init hook in your plugin file to register custom function

```
add_action( 'init', 'custom_proccess_form' );
```

And then check form inputs in the custom function, you mentioned creating posts

```
function custom_proccess_form() {

    $wp_error = true;   // report errors or not
    $nonce = $_POST['_wpnonce'];

    if( isset($_POST['insert_post']) && wp_verify_nonce($nonce, 'my-nonce-name') ) {

        $post = array(
            'post_title' => $_POST['new_post_title'],
            'post_content' => $_POST['new_post_content'],
            );

        // form actions
        $post_id = wp_insert_post( $post, $wp_error );

        // now you can use $post_id within add_post_meta or update_post_meta

        // redirect at the end to some url
        wp_redirect('/?success=true');
    }
}
```

The form itself could look like this

```
<form method="POST">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('my-nonce-name'); ?>
    <input type="text" name="new_post_title">
    <textarea name="new_post_content"></textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="insert_post" value="1">
    <button type="submit">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

Comment: ok looks neat. Is there functions for flash messages? (session message that are displayed and auto erased on redirection)

Comment: what is $wp_error used for?

Comment: optional parameter for WP error, good for testing, see https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_post

Comment: ok thx. is there a good third party form api to ease development? like form api in drupal

Comment: do you use bbpress? bp_loggedin_user_domain() returns null when i call it in my init hook, so not sure if it is the right place to handle form submission?

Comment: I like to use https://github.com/Anahkiasen/former - might take a little work to implement WP specific stuff (like nonce field), but its definitely worth it for future. If you prefer WP plugins, there is great one for handling custom fields - http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ and that one is able to print forms by calling acf_form() http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/how-to/create-a-front-end-form/

Comment: i dont use bbpress, but maybe you could lower the priority of the action by specifying something like `add_action( 'init', 'custom_proccess_form', 100 );`

Comment: i ended up using the hook wp_load and it works fine

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin created to get through out your problem submitting the form. a plugin were over  8 out of 10  wordpress sites have it for free  use contact-form-7 plugin by wordpress. these would make things easy